# here-api Time taken to travel the distance

Tags: here-api

I was trying the HERE routing maps to find out if it actually give me reasonable time for the distances that I already know. 
Source : 12.971076,77.537375
Destination: 12.975366,77.606841

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=12.971076,77.537375&waypoint1=12.975366,77.606841&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&departure=now&apiKey={API-Key}

I see that the API always gives me the time taken in between 33/34 minutes on all days of the week and all hours of the day.

Any idea on how the travel time is calculated?

In my opinion, for the above coordinates, during the rush hours it takes anywhere between 50-80 minutes.

Comment: Did you try to compare it with other maps as well at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I did with google. see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

We have replicated the same API, and got 2 different travel time by altering the value of departure. Can you please try to use below DEPARTURE time format.

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=12.971076,77.537375&waypoint1=12.975366,77.606841&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&departure=2020-03-19T13:00:00&apiKey=xxxxxx

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=12.971076,77.537375&waypoint1=12.975366,77.606841&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&departure=2020-03-19T10:00:00&apiKey=xxxxxx

Comment: Hello, I see that the time is varying based on departure. But the variation is negligible, I know for a fact, that it will take around 50-60 mins between those two points. I even tried google maps for the same for the departure are 13:30 on Monday March 16, it says, the time taken varies between 26 mins to 1 hr 5 mins. At 13:30 I think it would take around 40 - 45 mins. However at 10:00 AM it would take anywhere between 50 - 80 mins. Therefore, I wanted to understand how the time is calculated.